# What do I use to Enter, Retrieve, and/or Edit Project Details?

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I'm new to coding, so I'm having trouble knowing what to even search for to make my project work.

For our small construction company, I'm trying to build something that will store our project details; a database I suppose. As the title suggests, I need to be able to add new projects, retrieve past projects, or edit current projects.

In my mind, this can all be done on the same web page with the same form and maybe only a save button. So if I need to add a new job, I simply start typing the new job name. To retrieve a past job, I also simply start typing the name and autocomplete would find the record and bring up the details. Once it's loaded, if I need to edit something I scroll to the input, make my change and hit save.

Everything I've managed to find, so far, either costs money or is too clunky for my co-workers to feel comfortable using. And I feel like this is a relatively simple project, I just don't know where to start or what to learn.

Comment: It all sounds so easy... What could go wrong?

Comment: I just need someone to point me in a direction, I would love to hire someone but I don't think it's in the budget anytime soon And like I said, in my head, this seems like a pretty simple task. I just don't know if html forms with get/post and javascript would work, or if I should look into a cms or if there's a completely different solution out there. I need wisdom from people that actually do this stuff.

Comment: I would suggest using a mature, modern framework and go from there. You're going to need a community and lots of examples. My suggestion: Symfony (PHP, server application) and perhaps an AngularJS single-page app (Javascript, client-side) using something like Bootstrap or Foundation for the presentation layer. But I digress. See [this beginner's take](http://symfony.com/blog/a-beginner-s-journey-with-symfony) when starting Symfony from zero (your experience will probably not differ a lot, if you are tenacious enough), http://docs.behat.org/ (BDD), getcomposer.org and https://packagist.org/

Comment: Also, if your company doesn't value it enough to fund it adequately (including your time), you're working on a personal project. If your company owns that in the end, you're really only teaching yourself to program with a given project (which helps, but is worth pointing out). Limiting grandiosity and keeping real will help in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendations to you to accomplish this task would be either to:

1. Start learning `HTML` for the markup of your website and forms.
2. Continue with adding `CSS` to make the page more user friendly
3. Add some `Javascript` for validations and visual enhancements
4. Use `MySql` to store the information you need in a database
5. Add `PHP` to make the website dynamic and interact with the `database`
6. Some `AJAX` would really enhance the experience along with 3rd party libraries like `jQuery`

**OR**

another solution would be to hire a professional to do that for you, as that what i would do if i wanted to build a house, i would find a construction company such as yours instead of trying to do it all by myself without the know how and experience in the field as it would probably take me a lifetime to do it...

Comment: Fair point, but if steps 1-6 area actually a legitimate path to make this happen, I might know more than I realized. HTML and CSS are no problem and I know enough javascript, mysql, php and jquery to get by with help from google.

I suppose when I say I'm new to coding, I just haven't had much experience putting all those pieces together. I'm like a guy who can use a table saw, miter saw, and drill but just doesn't quite know when to use each or how to build something with them.

Your answer is actually encouraging to me that I might be on the right track, I just need to keep working.

Comment: That's good and it seems you have the right mindset but it will take some time, and probably many errors/problems for which if you cant find an answer to, SO is here to help you by identifying the problem and guiding you in the right track.

Comment: @user19678 - You are the perfect candidate for working with a framework approach (both client and server). My suggestion is Symfony 2 (well documented, feature-rich, lots of packages, etc.), but there are other competent entries: Laravel, Phoenix, even FuelPHP or Slim. If you want to get something up and going quickly, try Vagrant with a Symfony build included. For instance: https://github.com/kleiram/vagrant-symfony

Comment: thanks jared, I think I will give symfony a try, if you think my skill set should be able to handle it. Historically, I've had trouble getting up and running with frameworks.. Installing them and then understanding exactly what they're there for. I'm not very comfortable in terminal and I have this fear that once I get everything "finished" on my local machine, I'll have a terrible time getting everything live on a real server. But thanks for the suggestions, it does sound like a much better way for me to do things, rather than doing everything from scratch.

Comment: Given you are just starting out Laravel is a great candidate and has a great and easy to understand syntax and is based on top of Symphony.